# how to return back in webview on .net maui (ios)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, maui

I have an application with WebView and I want to return to the previous page in iOS platforms.

how i can do this?

the swipe to side also doesn't work, and I don't have any back button.

In contrast in Android, it works because have a back button and I used this function

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed(){
  if (webView.CanGoBack)
  {
    webView.GoBack();
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could be done by writing an ios custom renderer for webview, that sets [WKWebView.AllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webkit.wkwebview.allowsbackforwardnavigationgestures?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14). This would enable iOS swipe to side. Look for doc, or previous questions, to see how to write maui custom renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the page's OnHandlerChanged method to set `WKWebView.AllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures` as
ToolmakerSteve said.

In the Page's xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="webview" Source="">
```

In the Page's code behind:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if IOS
        var web = webview.Handler.PlatformView as Webkit.WKWebView;
        web.AllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true;
#endif
    }
```

Or you can use the [custom handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize#customize-a-specific-control-instance) to set all the webview's AllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures on the iOS.